# arcgis API 3.7 addLayer maybe problems with updating from 2.7?

Tags: arcgis

I'm trying to figure out why I am having issues converting a arcgis API 2.7 to 3.7, my primary issue is that that the API isn't loading the SolarTerminationLayer which is in a class by itself.  http://solarterminator-esri-jsapi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/layer.html  Is the example that I am working off of, it works perfectly in 2.7 but when converting to my 3.7 API project I'm running into problems.  Here is my code:

```
require(["esri/map", "dojo/parser", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/SolarTerminatorLayer", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"], 
function(Map, parser, domStyle, SolarTerminatorLayer ) {

    map = new Map("map", { 
        basemap: "topo",
        center: [-89.835, 38.545],
        zoom: 6,
        wrapAround180: true
    });

    parser.parse();

    var solarTerminatorLayer = new SolarTerminatorLayer({id: "lyrSolarTerminator", visible: true});
    map.addLayer(solarTerminatorLayer);
    solarTerminatorLayer.on("load", function() {
        domStyle.set("loading", "display", "none");
    });
});
```

I'm new to the ArcGIS API, so any answers would be greatly helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot of changes around version 3.4 with how additional libraries were loaded.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714463/how-to-set-arcgis-javascript-dojoconfig-relative-path-of-packages) has a few details on setting your dojoConfig correctly, you may need something like this:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: false,
    packages: [
        {
            name: "SolarTerminatorLayer",
            location: "../js",  /* Or where ever your code is */
            main: "SolarTerminatorLayer.js"
        }
    ]
};
```